# Expiry date for Glacier backups

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-glacier

Is there a way to set an expiry date in Amazon Glacier?  I want to copy in weekly backup files, but I dont want to hang on to more than 1 years worth.

Can the files be set to "expire" after one year, or is this something I will have to do manually?

Answer (score 14):

While not available natively within [Amazon Glacier](http://aws.amazon.com/glacier/), AWS has recently enabled [Archiving Amazon S3 Data to Amazon Glacier](http://aws.typepad.com/aws/2012/11/archive-s3-to-glacier.html), which makes working with Glacier much easier in the first place already:

> [...] Amazon S3 was designed for rapid retrieval. Glacier, in
>   contrast, trades off retrieval time for cost, providing storage for as
>   little at $0.01 per Gigabyte per month while retrieving data within
>   three to five hours.
>
> How would you like to have the best of both worlds? How about rapid
>   retrieval of fresh data stored in S3, with automatic, **policy-driven
>   archiving to lower cost Glacier storage as your data ages**, along with
>   easy, API-driven or console-powered retrieval? *[emphasis mine]*
>
> [...] You can now use Amazon Glacier as a storage option for Amazon S3.

This is enabled by facilitating Amazon S3 [Object Lifecycle Management](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html), which not only drives the mentioned [Object Archival (Transition Objects to the Glacier Storage Class)](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-archival.html) but also includes optional [Object Expiration](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ObjectExpiration.html), which allows you to achieve what you want as outlined in section *Before You Decide to Expire Objects* within [Lifecycle Configuration Rules](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html#intro-lifecycle-rules):

> - The Expiration action deletes objects
>     You might have objects in Amazon S3 or archived to Amazon Glacier. **No
>     matter where these objects are, Amazon S3 will delete them.** You will
>     no longer be able to access these objects. *[emphasis mine]*

So at the small price of having your objects stored in S3 for a short time (which actually eases working with Glacier a lot due to removing the need to manage archives/inventories) you gain the benefit of optional automatic expiration.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in the AWS Command Line Interface. 
http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/object-lifecycle-mgmt.html